# Erro "is not an enclosing class"

Tags: java, android, handler

Estou fazendo um exercício de *Handler* apenas para testar como funciona, mas estou tento algum problema que não consigo entender.

Este é o meu código da classe principal:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int MENSAGEM_TESTE = 1;
private Handler handler = new TesteHandler();
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Atualizar o texto em 3 segundos");
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //Cria msg com delay de 3 seg
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = MENSAGEM_TESTE;
            //Envia msg
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 3000);
        }
    });

}
}
```

E este é o código da minha classe `TesteHandler`:

```
import static com.exercicios.handler.MainActivity.MENSAGEM_TESTE;

public class TesteHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public  void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
           case MENSAGEM_TESTE:
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A mensagem chegou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

O Android Studio está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> 'com.exercicios.handler.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class.

Eu não estou encontrando o que preciso corrigir, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda, por favor? Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesta situação o erro *"not an enclosing class"* é devido ao uso incorrecto de `this`.

`this`, dentro de um método de instância ou construtor, refere-se ao objecto actual.

Ao usar `MainActivity.this` está a referir-se ao objecto `MainActivity` como se ele fosse o objecto actual mas o objecto actual é do tipo *TesteHandler*.

Traduzindo *"not an enclosing class"* seria *"não é uma classe envolvente"*.

Para que `MainActivity.this` seja válido dentro da classe *TesteHandler*, *MainActivity* tem de "envolver" a classe *TesteHandler*, ou seja, *TesteHandler* terá de ser uma *inner* classe de *MainActivity*.

Outra alternativa é passar a *MainActivity* ao construtor da classe *TesteHandler* para poder usá-la no *Toast*.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esta mensagem esteja ocorrendo ao realizar o `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this` na classe `TesteHandler`.

Tente passar o contexto no `Handler handler = new TesteHandler(getApplicationContext());`

Insira no `TesteHandler`

```
private Context ctx;
public TesteHandler(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

Em seu Toast, modifique para:

```
Toast.makeText(ctx,, "A mensagem chegou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Espero poder ter ajudado.